# Rails: Change json output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby

Here's the code `render json: news, :include => {:tags => {:only => :name}, :category => {:only => :name}}` which outputs this:

```
{
"id": 2,
"title": "title",
"tags": [],
"category": {
  "name": "lorem"
}
```

Is there any way to output it like this?

```
{
"id": 2,
"title": "title",
"tags": [],
"category": "lorem" # <--- display category name 
}
```

Comment: Are you using a serialization library? Can you include the details of this in your post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your News model, you could define:

```
def as_json(options={})
  {id: id, title: title, tags: tags}.tap do |hash|
    hash[:category] = category.name unless category.nil?
  end
end
```

And then simply: `render json: news`

You'll likely have to change the code in as_json to match whatever structure you've created for your model, but the idea is to create a hash using the format you want for your json, then let rails turn it into json.

Comment: now I get  `undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass` because not all News have category assigned. Is there any way to workaround it?

Comment: can you post the table entry for the news model from db/schema.rb? I can't write a working function for your news class without knowing its internals.

Comment: oh one second, i just saw your comment. i'll update my code.